# How to /give a named item in Minecraft PE

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I need to now how to give a player a named item with commands. I have tried it already on PC, and it works, but it does not work in PE.

Answer (score 0):

As of Version 1.1.3, using the `/give` command to give named items doesn't work. You can't customise NBT tags yet.

If you wanted to, you could give the player xp so that they could name it themselves on an anvil using the command `/xp <amount: int> [player:target]` or `/xp <amount:int>L [player:target]`.